# How to Detect when a CD / DVD / USB Inserted or Removed and Get Drive Letter?

Tags: delphi, usb, detection

I want to detect when a Disk ( CD / DVD ) or an USB inserted or removed.

I know that I should work with `WM_DEVICECHANGE` message , but my problem is getting the Volume ( Letter ) of the Drive , I tried to Get it by `WMI Query` and `Win32_VolumeChangeEvent` too but I could not!

[there is an Example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/UsbManager.aspx) and work fine , how can I do this by Delphi?

Comment: @menjaraz Fixed what? There's nothing to "fix" here...

Comment: @JerryDodge You are right! Sorry for the wrong wording, perhaps we should tidy up all these bunch of irrelevant comments polluting here?

Answer (score 2):

[Detecting Media Insertion or Removal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363215.aspx) (MSDN)
[Detecting Hardware Insertion and/or Removal](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/HwDetect.aspx) (codeproject.com)

// EDIT:

[...get notified when a CD is removed or inserted?](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=372) (Torry's Delphi Page)

and also

http://www.google.com/search?q=Delphi+WMDeviceChange

Comment: Nice, but not in delphi. However that should be enough to figure it out. Also interesting topic.

Comment: Yes, it's not Delphi. But it is not a C#! C++ and Objective Pascal are very close languages, translation will involve mainly some syntax correction and fit into Delphi's VCL framework.

Comment: @Bart: The Windows API looks the same in every programming language. If one knows a language (e.g. Delphi), one knows how to use external APIs in that language (Delphi).

Comment: @Andreas: I had this in my mind when I wrote that this should be enough. Also +1 to author now.

Answer (score 0):

For CD insertions, you want CDEvents: http://www.torry.net/vcl/filedrv/cd/dtcdevents.zip

Works beautifully. E-mail me (eknowles@gmail.com) if you want sample code.